# An object property of type function

Tags: qt, qml

I have an `InterstitialAd` QML object (QtQuick 2, QT 5.13) with `onClosed` event that is triggered with the interstitial ad is closed. I tried to show the interstitial ad before starting new game with the following QML code:

```
InterstitialAd {
    id: iAd

    property variant handlerFunc

    onClosed: {
        if (handlerFunc) {
            handlerFunc
            handlerFunc = null
        }
    }
}

function resetGameWithAd()
{
    iAd.handlerFunc = Qt.binding(function() {
        console.log("AdTest: calling resetGame()")
        scene.resetGame()
    })
    console.log("AdTest: calling iAd.show()")
    iAd.show()
}
```

where I tried to assign `handlerFunc` to a function that restarts the game when `onClosed` event is triggered, but got an effect that I did not expect. The console output of my app is:

```
qml: AdTest: calling resetGame()
qml: AdTest: calling iAd.show()
```

so obviously assigning `handlerFunc` to `Qt.binding...` actually calls the function (because `resetGame` is printed first), but I expected that it does only assignment. The similar technique is demonstrated [here, with ':' but not with assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27945427/qml-how-to-pass-javascript-function-as-argument-in-another-function).

**What is wrong and what is the right way to implement this?**

I also tried a code like this:

```
    function resetGameHandler(params)
    {
        iAd.closed.connect(function() {
            scene.resetGame(params)
            iAd.closed.disconnect(/*...???...*/) 
        })
        iAd.show();
    }
```

but with no success because [I can't disconnect it, without having a reference to the implicitly created function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496742/how-to-disconnect-the-method-for-a-signal-in-qml) (as far as I see it means that I need a regular function with a name).

Comment: Why do you wan't to register a callback, instead of directly binding a handler?

Comment: @derM The ad is shown when the user 1) starts a new game 2) change the game parameters 3) when the game is over 4) etc... so I ideally I need something like `std::function` in C++ that will be called when the ad is closed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I haven't done any QML for some months, so I might be wrong. But if my memory is any good, this might help you.

To stay close to your approach:

1. `variant` is deprecated. Using `var` instead is recommended.
2. You won't need `Qt.binding()`. You can directly assign a function to that property.
3. Call the function in the property.

---

```
InterstitialAd {
    id: iAd

    property var handlerFunc <-- Use var instead of variant

    onClosed: {
        if (handlerFunc && typeof handlerFunc === "function") {
            handlerFunc() <-- Call it!
            handlerFunc = null
        }
    }
}

iAd.handlerFunc = function() { // doSomething cool here }
```

Alternatively you might be able to produce the same results with `Binding` and `Connection`-Objects in a more declarative way, but the right choice depends on *what shall be done `onClosed`*

Comment: Cool.  I had written this same essential pattern to begin with, but it wouldn't work for me.  Your line: `handlerFunc() <-- Call it!` pointed out exactly what I was missing.  Of course! <Slapping head!>