# How to overload type function in QML?

Tags: qt, qml

I'm having trouble overloading a parent function. Here is a simplified example trying to overload the `getValue()` function:

```
// MyGauge.qml
CircularGauge {
    id: root
    width: 235
    height: 210
    function getValue() {
        return 100
    }

    value: getValue()
}

//main.qml
MyGauge {
    function getValue() {
        return 200
    }
}
```

When running main.qml I would expect to see a value of 200, but 100 is shown. According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41016410) answer, this should be working.

EDIT: I will provide a more complete example to show what I'm trying to accomplish. My CircularGauge has a complex CircularGaugeStyle. Most gauge's tick label text will just be the actual value of the tick. But ONE gauge should use different text; the values are too large so I want to make it an expression to divide by 1000. How do I do that for just this one gauge, without overriding the whole `CircularGaugeStyle` in the parent?

```
// MyGauge.qml
CircularGauge {
    id: root
    width: 235
    height: 210

    function tickmarkLabelText(value) {
        return value
    }

    function getColor(value) {
        return value >= 50 ? "#e34c22" : "#e5e5e5";
    }

    style: CircularGaugeStyle {

        // LOTS OF OTHER STYLES HERE

        tickmarkLabel:  Text {
            text: tickmarkLabelText(styleData.value) // I want to override just this function
            color: getColor(styleData.value)
            antialiasing: true
        }
    }
}

//main.qml
MyGauge {
    function tickmarkLabelText(value) {
        return value / 1000
    }
}
```

Comment: maybe you need to rewrite the "value" property in the child item. "value: getValue()"

Comment: Guess it's not working because you're trying to bind it to value property

Comment: I guess you have to rewrite `value: getValue()` in `MyGauge`.

Comment: I added a real example. The problem is I can't just rewrite the value, because it is embedded in a child object, which I don't think I can modify. What do I do in this case?